# Linking to tables and get results through view(blade)

Tags: laravel

```
@foreach ($despatchitems as $despatchitem)
<tr>
  <td>{{$despatchitem->tag_id}}</td>
  <td>{{$despatchitem->qty}}</td>
  <td>{{$despatchitem->description}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

i need to have the **tag name** instead of the **tag_id**, How can i make the connection to Tag table and get the tag name

There is no Direct relationship between **DespatchItem** Model and **Tag** Model

Comment: Show your query from the controller!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **belongsTo** relationship in your DespatchItem Model.

```
public function tags()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Tag','tag_id');
}
```

and Use in your View like below way.

```
<td>{{$despatchitem->tags->tag_name}}</td>
```